# update count from a table in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, sql-update

I am new to postgres so sry if this sound like a stupid question

I have a polygons shp in postgresql named t1 with fields like this

```
id  |  area  |  grid_id
1   |  10    |  01_01
2   |  100   |  01_02
3   |  1000  |  01_03
4   |  10    |  01_01
```

I want to count the poligons with a certain unique "grid_id" which I can make with

```
SELECT COUNT (*) from public.t1 group by grid_id
```

Now I want to update another table, t2, in a field "nr_polig" with the number of polygons corresponding to each unique grid_id

```
id  |  name  |  nr_polig
1   |  01_01 |  
2   |  01_02 |  
3   |  01_03 |  
4   |  01_04 |
```

I ve tried

```
Update public.t2 set nr_polig = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)  from public.t1 group by grid_id where public.grid_id = grid_id
)
```

### but its updating the total number of polygons

later_edit

it worked like this

```
UPDATE public.t2 
  set nr_polig = (SELECT COUNT (*) from public.t1 where public.t1.grid_id = public.t2.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the tables:

```
UPDATE public.t2
SET nr_polig = s.cnt
FROM (SELECT grid_id, count(*) AS cnt
      FROM public.t1
      GROUP BY grid_id) AS s
WHERE s.grid_id = t2.grid_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly *correlate* the subquery by prefixing column name with the table it belongs to. Also the `group by` clause is not needed in the subquery.

```
update t2 set nr_polig = (
    select count(*)  
    from t1
    where t1.grid_id = t2.name
)
```